# "error: main method not found", even if it's there

Tags: java, variables, program-entry-point

I'm a beginner with Java and I'm trying some exercises with variable types. I have just copied the following exercise and I'm trying to run it with NetBeans 7.4 (on a Windows computer):

```
public class ClassVariables {

    public static class Employee{  
        private static double salary;

        // 'DEPARTMENT' is a constant:
        public static final String DEPARTMENT = "Development ";


        public static void main(String[] args){
            salary = 1000;
            System.out.println(DEPARTMENT + "average salary: " + salary);
        }
    } 
}
```

There is no error or warning shown in the editor but when I run the code I get an error message that says:

```
"Error: Main method not found in class classvariables.ClassVariables, please define the main method as:
    public static void main(String[] args)"
```

I have already defined my main method as required but I keep getting this error message!

Could somebody help me out, please?

Comment: `classvariables.ClassVariables` is where your compiler searches for main method. check your run configuration

Comment: Dont make your Employee class static

Comment: The main method should be in the class ClassVariables, not in Employee.

Comment: Just Move second last `}` above main method.

Answer (score 2):

The outer class `ClassVariables` does not contain main method. The main method is written inside inner class. And you are trying to run the main method from class `ClassVariables` which is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Move your main method outside the scope of Employee class and place it inside the class ClassVariables

Comment: OK, thanks, I've done so, but now I get a new error message which says: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable salary
  location: class classvariables.ClassVariables
 at classvariables.ClassVariables.main(ClassVariables.java:54)
Java Result: 1".    The point of this exercise (which comes from Tutorial Point) is to learn how to use class/static variables...

Comment: This is because your field salary is defined in class Employee..You should define it in class ClassVariables

Comment: tick the answer if it helped you